# How to pass a function as parameter in kotlin - Android

Tags: android, function, parameters, kotlin

How to pass a function in android using Kotlin . I can able to pass if i know the function like :

```
fun a(b :() -> Unit){
}
fun b(){
}
```

I want to pass any function like ->
`fun passAnyFunc(fun : (?) ->Unit){}`

Comment: When you say "any function" do you really mean "every single function there possibly is"? Or just "any function that accepts one parameter of some type and returns `Unit`"?

Comment: Pass any function of any type as parameter of a function ? Did u understand now

Comment: Then that's not possible. This starts to sound like an XY problem. What do you plan on doing with the function (which can accept any number of parameters and return any type) that is passed in?

Comment: Hi @Sweeper below is the answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use anonymous function or a lambda as follows

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    fun something(exec: Boolean, func: () -> Unit) {
        if(exec) {
            func()
        }
    }

    //Anonymous function
    something(true, fun() {
        println("bleh")
    })

    //Lambda
    something(true) {
        println("bleh")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Yaswant Narayan .This only i was expecting

Comment: You could also pass lambda like
`something(true) { prinln("bleh") }`

Comment: How ? I didnt get you

Comment: `something()` accepts two parameters. One is a Boolean and other is a function itself. So `something()` become a higher order functions. For second parameter we pass something called lambda which simply is a function body enclosed with `{ ... }`. Since `something()` accepts a function as it's last parameter (which most higher order functions do) we can pass lambda outside function call like my previous post.

Answer (score 7):

Method as parameter Example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // Here passing 2 value of first parameter but second parameter
    // We are not passing any value here , just body is here
    calculation("value of two number is : ", { a, b ->  a * b} );
}

// In the implementation we will received two parameter
// 1. message  - message 
// 2. lamda method which holding two parameter a and b
fun calculation(message: String, method_as_param: (a:Int, b:Int) -> Int) {
     // Here we get method as parameter and require 2 params and add value
     // to this two parameter which calculate and return expected value
     val result = method_as_param(10, 10);

     // print and see the result.
     println(message + result)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an interface:

```
interface YourInterface {
    fun functionToCall(param: String)
}

fun yourFunction(delegate: YourInterface) {
  delegate.functionToCall("Hello")
}

yourFunction(object : YourInterface {
  override fun functionToCall(param: String) {
    // param = hello
  }
})
```

Comment: I can pass any interface I want common method so for this I need to create different Interface for different methods.

Answer (score 1):

First declare a lambda function(a function without name is known as lamdda function. its comes from kotlin standard lib not kotlin langauage which strat with {} ) in Oncreate like below

```
 var lambda={a:Int,b:Int->a+b}
```

Now Create a function which accept another function as a parameter  like below

```
fun Addition(c:Int, lambda:(Int, Int)-> Int){
    var result = c+lambda(10,25)
    println(result)

}
```

Now Call Addition function in onCreate by passing lambda as parameter like below

```
Addition(10,lambda)//  output 45
```