# Kotlin: Interface as method parameter

Tags: java, kotlin, interface

Is there any alternative way to pass interface as parameter to method like in java?

```
public class ReverseList { 
    interface NodeList {
        int getItem();
        NodeList nextNode();
    }
    void reverse(NodeList node) {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need an alternative?

Comment: As in the above code piece, it is very useful to pass interface as method parameter.

Comment: Yes, you just proved my point. _You don't need an alternative_. You should just do it - accept an interface as a parameter.

Comment: But don't know how to do it in Kotlin as I am working in Kotlin

Comment: Paste the java code in Intellij in any kotlin file :p. Voting to close the question.

Comment: And try to use lambda instead if you aren't concerned about interop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206233/how-to-pass-a-function-as-parameter-in-kotlin-android/51206375

Comment: You pass an interface as a parameter the same way you pass anything else: `fun reverse(node: NodeList)`.

Comment: Yes before asking question here I did, but IDE did not recognize the interface, even if I've imported.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a property

```
val handler = object: Handler {
override fun onComplete() {

}
```

}

Comment: How this is linked with above code? Could you please elaborate with example?

Comment: Don't know why this was down voted.